# Does it cost extra if I have to check my bag at boarding even if I have one free check-in?

Tags: air-travel, airports, hand-luggage

Lets say my flight allows for one checked luggage included in the ticket price.
Now I only bring cabin luggage but at the gate they then decide that my bag has to be checked-in because they find it too large or their scale says its overweight.

Would they then charge me a fee even though I can check-in one bag for free?
If so this would probably differ between airline but I was wondering if that is a thing at all.

Comment: As long as you are going to check-in just 1 bag and it is within the weight limits, there should be no extra charge. I am not sure whether this would be airline specific or not. Never heard of an airline charging a passenger in such a scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For non-LCC flights, usually gate checked luggage is free, especially if the gate crew or flight crew force you to do it. This is often because the gate crew is incentivized to board the plane quickly so that the flight isn’t delayed. And unlike the ticket counter crew, there’s little  monitoring of their revenue generation.

Some people do deliberately take advantage of this revenue loophole but I’d rather them do it this way than hauling their huge bags onboard.

LCCs are much stricter. I don’t have as much experience with them so I’ll leave it to another person to respond with an LCC-based answer.

Comment: I'd say this depends very much on the airline involved. Many airlines (especially LCCs) fine passengers who have a check a bag at the gate due to size/weight.